# How do I embed html above the Wall feed on a Page?

Tags: facebook, heroku

I have an audio stream I'd like to include on a Facebook Page, above or at the top of, the wall. Apparently BBC did this (though I can't find the link). Any suggestions on where I should start? I have the html hosted as a Heroku app right now, and can get it to display as a separate link on the Page. But how do I move it from it's own page and onto the Wall?

Thanks much from a FB Developer newbie,
Peter

Comment: would this be something similar to what you are speaking of pedstrom 
https://www.facebook.com/bbc1xtra?sk=app_196506863720166  i noticed that when on air this tab auto plays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Peter i believe what you might have seen is actually a page tab, with a feed app included to which they would have developed the feed itself as part of the tab..

tab http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs

if you wish to inlucude a flash movie or audio on the wall itself as a post.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/#audiovideo

if you can find us the link to the page you seen this on it would help alot.

Comment: Could be, but he did say it was above the wall - it's also against policy to auto-play any content in your iframe so i'm almost sure BBC wouldn't be doing that given that they're a high profile partner

Comment: That is why i was thinking it might be a page tab and his browser might have autoplay for what ever reason...., and about the auto play i agree i have never seen bbc auto play in stream or tab.  I have seen though on there tabs, really nice replicas of the wall feed, which could confuse a user.

A link would help alot.

Comment: The [bbc1xtra](https://www.facebook.com/bbc1xtra?sk=app_196506863720166) thing looks pretty close, though I thought the wall was below. Perhaps I was mistaken and that it was page tab? The open graph bits would be helpful, but for now I just want to get an audio stream up and available. It doesn't need to be auto-play, but more prominent than a page tab would be nice.

Comment: Does the [audio video open graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/#audiovideo) bits work with audio streams?

Comment: The open graph tags work for allowing the files to embed into the wall or news feed.  If you where to build a page tab the tags would not be needed.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, there's no way to embed custom content into a facebook page wall, except via the existing public APIs (none of which will allow auto playing of audio content - this is deliberate)

Comment: could he be stuck on og meta? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/#audiovideo

I looked at all the bbc pages, did not see any page tabs with audio either perhaps what you seen was a page tab https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/